# WSO2 DSS - in wso2dss how to display all data of all tables

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

In WSO2 DSS, from SQL Server: how can I extract all data from my database without writing a select for each table - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the SQL select statements in order to expose your datasource as a service. However , in order to make the process easier you can use the [generate feature](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/Generating+a+Data+Service), where it generate the dataservice for you.